# como hago para deshabilitar un JTextfield al seleccionar un items de un JComboBox

Tags: java, netbeans

Tengo una Duda... ¿alguien me puede ayudar por favor?
como hago para deshabilitar un JTextfield al seleccionar un items de un JComboBox...

la lista de items del JComboBox son:

-seleccionar-
Estudante
Profesor

(al escoger Estudiante deshabilitar el Jtexfield llamado JTextField_Asiganatura )

PDT: Mi JTextfield se llama JTextField_Asiganatura y Mi JComboBox se llama JComboBox_Rol

Answer (score 0):

Crea un método ItemStateChanged, si estás usando Netbeans puedes dar click derecho al combo box ---> eventos ---> Item ---> ItemStateChanged.

```
private void JComboBox_RolItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                       
    if(JComboBox_Rol.getSelectedItem().equals("Estudante")){
        JTextField_Asiganatura.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        JTextField_Asiganatura.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Con eso debería bastar.